# PhoneGap with Native Tabbar / Header UI -> Add & change

Tags: jquery, iphone, xcode, jqtouch, cordova

I'm building a project in jQTouch & PhoneGap.  After building the app in jQTouch, i'm at the point where I need to start adding in the fixed header & tabbar to navigate between sections.

I used this post to get the components visible: http://phonegap.pbworks.com/iPhone%3A-UIControls-%28TabBar%29

Can i please get some help with:

1. Adding 'back' buttons to the native header.  These were auto added in jQTouch, but as the header is being replaced by the native component, i need to figure out another way to add them back in to navigate within each section.
2. I'd also like to add an 'info' button to the right side of the header (which again was easy in jQTouch, but now needs to be replaced)
3. Is there any information (i've been unable to find), on how to alter the colours/styles of the phonegap native header & tabbar.  Along with new icons for the tabbar.

Many thanks,
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to answers questions one at a time

1) the title bar in the control is not a Navigation Bar; you add the back buttons and such to a navigation bar.

2) To add buttons to the title bar, you would have to customize the plugin since the feature is currently not supported

3) I believe you can get additional icons for the tab bar, but from looking at the code, it appears that you would have to do some customization of the plugin.